# Unable to delete SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

Everything began when my laptop (MSI PS63 Modern) went on being stuck in a BIOS boot loop back a few months ago. From what I remember, it happened after a BSOD where windows got frozen during the automatic repairing of that crash. I waited a few hours hoping I wouldn't have to force the system down but had to do it ultimately.

I recently tried to fix the Windows booting issue, unsuccessfully. To resume what I tried few days ago :

- Unable to access WindowsRE
- Reset the factory setting in BIOS and checked boot order
- Using a Windows Installation Media bootable key, tried the Windows Automatic Startup Repair which failed, tried to install a new OS with custom install on C:\ drive which failed and exited to a bios loop again.
- Using Command Prompt, tried "Bootrec /fixboot" but access was denied, even after the "common trick" of assigning a letter to it partition and copying bootfiles from C:\ to the EFI partition
- Tried rebuilding BCD

I abdicated and saved users data in another drive with a view to format the whole SSD to do a Windows clean install. Unfortunatley, was unable to wipe it and I used all the common methods I knew which were :

- Tried through Command Prompt from the USB flash drive, using diskpart. It seemed "clean" and "delete partition" or "delete volume" commands denied access. Tried to override them which seemed to work at first, but didn't when listing partitions again, even after restart.
- Tried to boot through Lubuntu OS on USB drive, but KDE Partition Manager didn't do the trick either.
- Finally I phisically removed the SSD from laptop to plug it in another PC, hoping Windows Disk Manager or any other (I tried miniTool) would manage to wipe that SSD down. But even trying to fill all sectors with zeros won't work, even if miniTool seems to accept and start the process, after which it calls it a success and display my old drive as it was before.
- I ran a surface test which turned out to be good.
- I suspect that this drive has been protected by Windows during BSOD repair and won't let me access to any writing, but even after running an attributes disk clear readonly on diskpart, nothing wants to be deleted on that disk. Seems i found the most undeletable data of all times (and to think that I was worried about data loss at first is quite laughable --')

I never encountered such a problem for such a simple task. I've tried all the basic tutorials I was able to find on this subject. I feel quite a bit of desperation and don't know what to do next... Any help would be much appreciated.

PS : Sry about the length and poor english.
Here is a CrystalDiskInfo of that drive and a DiskGenius formatting attempt:

[image: CrystalDisk screenshot]

[DiskGenius screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpQaf.png)

Comment: Can we see SMART (screenshot of CrystalDiskInfo for example)?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I just edited my post to add a CrystalDiskInfo screenshot.

Comment: It sounds like the drive has simply failed. SD cards and SSD devices regularly go read-only when the flash chips fail.

Comment: `But even trying to fill all sectors with zeros` .. never do this with an SSD.  It is not anything like HDD.

Comment: Hello @Mokubai and thanks for your answer. Is there any way I can make sure the chip definietely failed ?

Comment: You've pretty much proven it by trying to write/erase it on multiple computers.

Comment: BTW, the long attempt to repair the files system may be what destroyed the SSD. They have limited *write* cycles, and the continually churning did it in. At least there's no worthwhile data on it, if you're willing to wipe it.  You could try another third-party tool, such as DiskGenius, to 1. Remove all partitions. 2. Create a new partition. 3. Format it.  4. Commit all changes! However, if MiniTools could not, I'm not sanguine another app could.

Comment: https://superuser.com/search?q=SSD+read+only

Comment: SMART looks clean, no problems revealed there.

Comment: Other than number of log entries? - Not sure, unfortunately CrystalDiskInfo can't show those.

Comment: Normally, ideally, SMART shows when SSD is read-only. In this case it doesn't (ID 01 attribute).

Comment: Didn't know about that @Señor CMasMas, but I did just read that it is indeed useless and only reduces lifespan of the SSD by writing an unnecessary number of times on it.

Comment: Thank you @DrMoishe Pippik ! Do you mean that the first BSOD auto repair from Windows itself might have smoked my SSD by writing on it too many times ? 
Well actually the data seems unchanged and readable, since i managed to make a copy of the whole users folder. The undeletable side is what concerns me, now that I've been able to recover all worthwile data.
I tried it with DiskGenius, but it failed again as you predicted. I will still upload a screen of the raised errors.

Comment: Thank you again @Joep van Steen, is there any other kind of locking mechanism - apart from read-only state - that might share those symptoms ?

Comment: @GrandeSurface, what you are observing is likely a normal, "graceful", failure of an SSD. At the point where it can no longer write data, the controller sets it to read-only -- permanently. https://linustechtips.com/topic/1372371-read-only-mode-of-ssd/ This is better than allowing the SSD to overwrite data during failure.

Comment: Ok noted, thank you all very much for your help and RIP good old SSD ! Any suggestions about how to destroy the disk in order to permanently prevent accessing to the remaining data ? I guess I'm leaning towards hammering the shit out of it haha

Comment: A hammer would be useful.

Comment: Remove the cover and be creative using an angle grider to have a visual proof of destruction of the integrated circuits. Don't forget to wear protection goggles.